# Windows Phone: How to set height of a stackpanel?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have two textblocks inside a stackpanel. I fix my textblock height to 66. I also set the stackpanel height to 66. However, when I am running my app the height of stackpanel is always bigger than height of my textblocks. Do you know how can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height of a stackpanel configured to stack elements vertically makes no sense : the height will always be the sum of the heights of the elements of the panel.

Your problem is most likely the margin of the textbocks. Remove it and the panel will have the right size:

```
<TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

Comment: Kookiz I am adding the stackpannel programmatically. In other words, I have a for loop that each time add two textblocks to my stachpanel, then add stachpanel to my listbox. I did not set any margin for it.

Comment: @BahadorSaket Most controls have a default margin. Therefore, if you didn't explicitly set the margin to 0, they have one.